# Upgrade do laravel 5.7 para o 5.8

Tags: laravel

Bom dia prezados,

Estou realizando a migração do meu projeto pessoal do laravel 5.7 pra o 5.8, porém há uma parte na documentação que eu não entendi muito bem, pode ser uma pergunta boba, mas não consigo encontrar nada a respeito.

> All array_* and str_* global helpers have been deprecated. You should use the Illuminate\Support\Arr and Illuminate\Support\Str methods directly.

O que isso impacta no meu projeto?
Pelo que eu entendi os helpers do tipo array_* devem ser substituídos pelo Arr, então onde tenho por exemplo `array_push` devo substituir por `Illuminate\Support\Arr::prepend` neste caso?

Se alguém puder me tirar esta dúvida agradeço!

Comment: Não entendo algumas votações negativas em perguntas, esta me parece legítima e dentro do escopo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tem sentido algum substituir as funções nativas do PHP pelas funções do Laravel, a mensagem se refere as funções globais do Laravel, não tem nada haver com array_push ou str_replace, que são nativas.

As funções do Laravel (não nativas do PHP) eram as que estavam documentadas até a versão 5.6: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers, simplesmente veja o que esta documentado no Laravel 5.8 para helpers e verá quais funções estão disponíveis: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers

Algumas das funções descontinuas:

- array_add
- array_collapse
- array_divide
- array_dot
- array_except
- array_first
- array_flatten
- array_forget
- array_get
- array_has
- array_last
- array_only
- array_pluck
- array_prepend
- array_pull
- array_random
- array_set
- array_sort
- array_sort_recursive
- array_where
- array_wrap
- str_after
- str_before
- str_contains
- str_finish
- str_is
- str_limit
- str_plural
- str_random
- str_replace_array
- str_replace_first
- str_replace_last
- str_singular
- str_slug
- str_start

Veja que nenhuma tem haver com as nativas do PHP

Comment: Valeu, ultimamente não tenho programado muito em php, no meu trabalho utilizo VB e C#, e no emprego anterior utilizava typescript, então andava meio enferrujado, Obrigado pelo esclarecimento!!